# A point-wise separation Hahn-Banach theorem in C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. We denote  $K(H)$ by the space of compact operators on $H$ which is a two sided ideal in $B(H)$.

Let $E$ be a norm closed convex subset of positive operators in $K(H)$ and let $a$ be a non-zero positive compact operator  where $a\notin E$.

Q: Is there any vector $\zeta\in H$ which separates $a$ and $E$, I mean there is a a positive number $\lambda$ such that for all $x\in E$
$$ \langle x\zeta,\zeta\rangle\leq \lambda< \langle a\zeta,\zeta\rangle$$

Comment: Norm closed, or wot closed? Also, $a=0$ would be a counterexample to your inequality: you need to at least allow for the reversal of roles.

Comment: Dear Martin, please see the edit version.

Comment: there is  a paper by W. Arveson "Non commutative Hahn banach theorem". It may contains some materials related to your question.

Comment: Thanks Ali. It has a  nice discussion concerning  the extension Hahn-Banach theorem in the category of non-commutative functional analysis (operator spaces).